# urlopen for loop with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, urlopen

New user here. I'm *starting* to get the hang of Python syntax but keep getting thrown off by for loops. I understand each scenario I've reach on SO thus far (and my previous examples), but can't seem to come up with one for my current scenario.

I am playing around with BeautifulSoup to extract features from app stores as an exercise.

I created a list of both GooglePlay and iTunes urls to play around with.

```
 list = {"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tov.google.ben10Xenodromeplus&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doraemon.doraemonRepairShopSeasons&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KnowledgeAdventure.SchoolOfDragons&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.stevenrpg&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indigokids.mimdoctor&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.gold&hl=en",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump/id307727765?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flick-home-run-!/id454086751?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bike-race-pro/id510461370?mt=8"}
```

To test out beautifulsoup (bs in my code), I used one app for each store:

```
gptest = bs(urllib.urlopen("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.gold&hl=en"))

ios = bs(urllib.urlopen("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump/id307727765?mt=8"))
```

I found an app's category on iTunes using:

```
print ios.find(itemprop="applicationCategory").get_text()
```

...and on Google Play:

```
print gptest.find(itemprop="genre").get_text()
```

With this newfound confidence, I wanted to try to iterate through my entire list and output these values, but then I realized I suck at for loops...

Here's my attempt:

```
def opensite():
for item in list:
    bs(urllib.urlopen())

for item in list:
try:
    if "itunes.apple.com" in row:
        print "Category:", opensite.find(itemprop="applicationCategory").get_text()
    else if "play.google.com" in row:
        print "Category", opensite.find(itemprop="genre").get_text()
except:
    pass
```

Note: Ideally I'd be passing a csv (called "sample" with one column "URL") so I believe my loop would start with

```
for row in sample.URL:
```

but I figured it was more helpful to show you a list rather than deal with a data frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function   #
try:                                    #
    from urllib import urlopen          # Support Python 2 and 3
except ImportError:                     #
    from urllib.request import urlopen  #

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

for line in open('urls.dat'): # Read urls from file line by line
    doc = bs(urlopen(line.strip()), 'html5lib') # Strip \n from url, open it and parse
    if 'apple.com' in line:
        prop = 'applicationCategory'
    elif 'google.com' in line:
        prop = 'genre'
    else:
        continue
    print(doc.find(itemprop=prop).get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for reading urls from list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2
import requests

list = {"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tov.google.ben10Xenodromeplus&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doraemon.doraemonRepairShopSeasons&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KnowledgeAdventure.SchoolOfDragons&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.stevenrpg&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indigokids.mimdoctor&hl=en",
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.gold&hl=en",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump/id307727765?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flick-home-run-!/id454086751?mt=8",
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bike-race-pro/id510461370?mt=8"}

def opensite():
    for item in list:
        bs(urllib2.urlopen(item),"html.parser")
        source = requests.get(item)
        text_new = source.text
        soup = bs(text_new, "html.parser")

        try:
            if "itunes.apple.com" in item:
                print item,"Category:",soup.find('span',{'itemprop':'applicationCategory'}).text
            elif "play.google.com" in item:
                print item,"Category:", soup.find('span',{'itemprop':'genre'}).text
        except:
            pass

opensite()
```

It will print like

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump/id307727765?mt=8 Category: Games
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KnowledgeAdventure.SchoolOfDragons&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tov.google.ben10Xenodromeplus&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8 Category: Games
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doraemon.doraemonRepairShopSeasons&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8 Category: Games
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indigokids.mimdoctor&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bike-race-pro/id510461370?mt=8 Category: Games
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.gold&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.stevenrpg&hl=en Category: Role Playing
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flick-home-run-!/id454086751?mt=8 Category: Games
```